# MVC5 and Dynamic Route issues

Tags: parameters, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a very strange and annoying problem that I need some help with desperately. I have a Dynamic Route that all request will go through in my MVC application. The route looks like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "FirstSpirit",
                "{locale}/{*PageUrl}",
                new { controller = "Site", action = "Page" },
                new { PageUrl = @"^(.*)?$" } //^(.*)?$
                );
```

so this is fine however 2 things are happening that I can't find direct answers to.

The first thing is that the {locale} parameter is not populated if the value is "en". For example if I use the URL http://domain.com/es/index.html then the value "es" comes through in the routedata values. However if i use the URL http://domain.com/en/index.html the value "en" does not come through. This works with every other value but "en" and I can't figure out why.

The other issue I have is that I need to be able to pass .html in the URL using the same route but if I use the .html extension in my URL the MVC app automatically throws a 404 and doesn't hit any of my routes or controllers.

Can someone help me please as I am going a little crazy with this. Sorry if this has been answered before but I just can't find anything on these issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the advantage of having a look at the application source code. Interestingly, the routing worked correctly for me.

The issue was replicated on Windows Server 2012 R2 Data Centre (.NET v4.6 [393297]).

I couldn't replicate on Windows 10 (.NET v4.6 [393295]).

I removed the following from web.config:

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

Added:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

And changed the targetFramework from `4.5.2` to `4.5`.

This change seemed to address the fact that IIS wasn't routing all requests to the application. However, "en" is STILL being removed from the url that the Controller Action receives as a catch all parameter. This is only stripped when "en/" is the first part of the url path.

e.g.

/something/en/index.html resolves as "something/en/index.html".
/en/index.html resolves as "index.html".